# How can I get the name id of a link from a click event?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$('#status-infos')
    .on('click', '#manageLink, #loginLink, #registerLink', function (e) {
        var $link = $(this);
        var abc = ???
```

How can I populate the string abc with "#manageLink" "#loginLink" or "registerLink" depending on which is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely JS:

```
var abc = this.id;
```

With jQuery:

```
var $link = $(this);
var abc = $link.attr("id");
```

Comment: Why using two steps and not directly $(this).attr('id'); ?

Comment: @yan.kun i know what you mean. I was just finishing what the OP left as a question mark :).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#status-infos').on('click', '#manageLink, #loginLink, #registerLink', function (e) {
        var $link = $(this);
        var s = $link.attr("id");  // $link.prop("id");
});
```

And You can also get the id by:

```
$('#status-infos').on('click', '#manageLink, #loginLink, #registerLink', function (e) {
        var s = e.target.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this...

```
$link.attr('id');
```

might work...